# How to solve inequalities which have absolute value inside absolute value?

Tags: inequality

I know how to solve if I have something like this: $$|2x + 3| - |1 - x| \geq 3$$

But I don't know how to solve something like this: $$|x + |3x + 9|| \geq 3$$

Anyone can show me how to start solving this type of absolute value in inequalities?

Comment: take cases for the absolute inside the absolute and then for each one of these cases , take cases again for the remaining absolute quantity!

Comment: The outter abs goes away?

Comment: @BjörnFriedrich "What happens when you square both sides?" An awful mess?

Comment: Split into two equations $x+\mid 3x+9 \mid\leq-3$ or $x+\mid 3x+9 \mid\geq3$.

Comment: @KayK. based on what I can do that? Then I get 2 intervals and make intersection between them?

Comment: Not intersection but 'union' as it is 'or'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is the same as you do it when you have only one absolute sign. I would do the following;
$x + |3x+9| \geq 3$ or $x + |3x+9| < -3$

$|3x+9| \geq 3-x$ or $|3x+9| < -3-x$

case 1. $|3x+9| \geq 3-x$

case 2. $|3x+9| < -3-x$

Let's consider case 1 first,

**case 1.**

$|3x+9| \geq 3-x$

$3x+9 \geq 3-x$  or $3x+9 < -(3-x)$

$4x \geq -6$  or $ 2x < -12$

$x \geq -3/2$ or $x < -6$.

Now consider case 2.

**Case 2**

$|3x+9| < -3-x$

$3x+9 < -3-x$ or $3x-9 \geq 3+x$

$x < -3$ or $x \geq -3$

Now for the final answer,  you have to consider 4 regions of $x$ values;

$x \geq -3/2$ or $x <-6$ or $x <-3$ or $x >= -3$

That is, the answer is :

$(-\infty , -6) \cup [-3, \infty)$

Hope this helps you.

Thanks.

Comment: why did you take in case 1. : -(3-x) ?

Comment: in case 1, again you want to remove the absolute value sign so you consider one $\geq a$ and the other $\leq -a$. where $a = 3-x$ in this case.

Comment: Yes, I understood, I'm just doing a bit differently. I did it, thanks :) :) :) Checked solutions with mathematica and it was right. But the thing that's bothering me is: If I get "x >= -3" for one solution and "x <= -3" for other solution, why do I take "x = -3" and not x is element of real numbers? Because "x" in this example must be the same number?

Comment: Until the split into case 1 and case 2, you are good. After that, in case 1 you use the equivalence $|u|\geqslant v\iff (u\geqslant v\lor u\leqslant-v)$ and in case 2 you use the equivalence $|u|\leqslant v\iff (u\leqslant v\lor u\geqslant-v)$. None of them holds, for example, $|u|\geqslant v\iff (v\leqslant0\lor u\geqslant v\geqslant0\lor u\leqslant-v\leqslant0)$.

Comment: @ Jerman, If you have $x \geq 3$ and  $x \leq -3$ , the only possible value we can take for $x$ is $x=-3$ . Draw on the real line, and see the common region for the final answer.

Comment: If you have $x \geq -3$ or $x \leq -3$, then your final answer would be $ -\infty \leq x \leq \infty$.

Comment: If you agree with the answer, please don't forget to click like. Thanks.

Comment: But for case 1. I take union of $x ≥ -3/2$ and $ x ≤ -6$ . But for case 2. I take intersection. I'm I thinking right?

Comment: @ Jerman, For case 2, $ 3x +9 \leq -3-x$ or $3x - 9 \geq 3+x$   .  

that means $4x \leq -12 $ or $ 2x \geq 12$.  

That is, $x \leq -4/3$ or $x \geq 6$

Now you have $x \geq -3/2$ or $x \leq -6$ or $x \leq -4/3$ or $x \geq 6$

So the final answer : $- \infty \leq x \leq \infty$. 

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

One simple way: split it into cases.

$$|x+|3x+9||\geqslant 3$$

#### Case 1

If $x+|3x+9| \geqslant 0$ then $x+|3x+9|\geqslant 3$.

$$|3x+9| \geqslant -x \implies x\in(-\infty;-\tfrac92\rangle \cup \langle -\tfrac94;+\infty)=A$$
$$|3x+9|\geqslant 3 - x \implies x\in(-\infty;-6\rangle \cup \langle -\tfrac32;+\infty)=B$$
$$\Downarrow$$
$$x\in A\cap B=(-\infty;-6\rangle \cup \langle -\tfrac32;+\infty) = S_1$$
The set above contains the solutions from this case.

#### Case 2

If $x+|3x+9| < 0$ then $-x-|3x+9|\geqslant 3$.

$$|3x+9| < -x \implies x\in(-\tfrac92;-\tfrac94)=A$$
$$-x-|3x+9|\geqslant 3 \implies x\in\{-3\}=B$$
$$\Downarrow$$
$$x\in A\cap B=\{-3\}=S_2$$

#### Summary

$$x\in S_1\cup S_2=(-\infty;-6\rangle \cup \{-3\}\cup \langle -\tfrac32;+\infty)$$